# What is the meaning of this command line

Tags: c++, vim, g++, command-line-interface

`g++ -fsanitize=address -std=c++17 -Wall -Wextra -Wshadow -DONPC -O2 -o %< % && ./%< < inp`

Especially last part with bizzare symbol sequence

Line was taken from some .vimrc file i wanted to copy

Comment: Have you tried to read some VIM documentation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lets break it down:

`g++` = Your compiler

`-fsanitize=address` = Compiler flags which adds address sanitizing. Increasing memory usage but also useful for debugging memory issues.

`-std=c++17` = Your C++ standard

`-Wall -Wextra -Wshadow` = Your compiler error flags

`-DONPC` = A compilation define for ONPC

`-O2` = A mild optimization flag

`-o` = The name of your compiled output-file

`%<` = In vim this stands for the main part of your filename

`%` = In vim this stands for your full filename, which you are compiling

`&&` = Indicating a second command

`./%<` = Run the output-file you just created

`< inp` = With this as input

I hope this clears things up. For further information, I'd recommend reading up on the vim and g++ documentation. Maybe even on bash `&&` You can find all this information in there.

Comment: `&&`  to run right-side command if left one had succeeded, afaik